# How to remove in the wordpress database all posts revisions except the last three?

Tags: sql, optimization, revisions

here is the commonly recommended sql command for removing posts revisions and cleaning up the wp database:

```
DELETE a,b,c
FROM `wp_posts` a
LEFT JOIN `wp_term_relationships` b ON (a.ID = b.object_id)
LEFT JOIN `wp_postmeta` c ON (a.ID = c.post_id)
WHERE a.post_type = 'revision';
```

how can i modify it to keep let's say the last 3 revisions ?

Comment: Please rework your question to bring into WP context. So far it's just plain SQL and would belong to SO.

Comment: well, these tables and the revision system i am talking about is wordpress specific

Comment: It doesn't matter if those tables exist in WordPress. The could as well live in a fork named _WorkDress_ and work similar. What exactly is WordPress specific about your question? Do you use `$wpdb`? No. Do you want to know where this is best hooked? No. Do you want to have WPDB Error output? No.

Comment: Btw, please also rework your question to use proper Capital letters. All the questions on the SE network shall be easily readable for later readers as well who face the same problem.

Comment: to put in another words: how wordpress store in dbs post revisions? and how can i select using sql query only a subset of revision ?

Comment: If you don't care and don't invest time editing your question, why should others care and take the time (for free) and invest their effort and time? Guess this question will simply get close voted.

Comment: well i appreciate your time...i do but so far u bring me more problem than solution.. i don't understand what is so wrong about my question ..it is specific to wordpress...else i wont ask this community. tell me more clearly what u expect and i will do my best to fit "your" requirements

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent more than three revisions from being saved to the database in the future by adding this line to your `wp-config.php` file:

```
define( 'WP_POST_REVISIONS', 3 );
```

That line should limit new posts to three revisions, but it won't go through your database and clean it up.

The SQL snippet that you found for deleting old revisions from the WordPress database has problems, which you can read about in [this thread on WordPress.org](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/deleting-post-revisions-do-not-use-the-abc-join-code-you-see-everywhere?replies=4).  The thread outlines the problems, and offers alternatives.  The thread also reviews some plugins that will do this for you.

Comment: thanks very much for that, i will look at this thoroughly

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach to delete all revisions except the **last one** (I know its not what was asked originally but I hope this helps somebody to use a similar solution).

**Step 1.** Create temporary table with the revisions that you want to keep:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t_keep_revisions;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t_keep_revisions AS (
    SELECT 
        MAX(p.ID) as ID,
        p.post_parent
    FROM wp_posts p
    WHERE p.post_type = 'revision'
    GROUP BY p.post_parent
    ORDER BY p.post_parent
);
```

**Step 2.** Delete all Revision Posts except those which ID is in the table created above

```
DELETE FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_type = 'revision'
AND ID NOT IN (
    SELECT ID
    FROM t_keep_revisions
);
```

**Step 3.** Delete orphan metadata from wp_postmeta

```
DELETE FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE post_id NOT IN (
    SELECT ID FROM wp_posts
)
```